# Hide Active Admin scope tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In Active Admin, I have added a scope for a particular model. I want to use the scope to filter results but since it is a single scope I dont want the tab to be shown on the top of the page. Is there a way to hide the tab on the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's supposed to be your default scope and there are no others, you can use `scope_to`, or you can override `scoped_collection`, [both of which are documented here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#scoping-the-queries).

For example:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.my_scope
  end
end
```